# Why is Redux dispatch taking this much time?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I open a file which is parsed and then dispatched into redux state. Timing the dispatch gives me much longer times than expexted. It seems like the dispatch itself takes several hundred milliseconds longer than the reducer.

After opening and parsing the file the following dispatch is called. The batch is there for the timing function.

```js
batch(() => {
  const t = performance.now();
  dispatch(
      setNewOpenFile({
          filePath,
          unpackedData,
      })
  );
  console.log('Time for dispatch: ', (performance.now() - t) + " ms"); 
})
```

Inside `setNewOpenFile` reducer:

```js
setNewOpenFile: (
    state,
    action: PayloadAction<{
        filePath: string;
        unpackedData: ParsedFile;
      }>
    ) => {
        const t0 = performance.now();
        const { unpackedData, filePath } = action.payload;

        const t1 = performance.now();
        const fileContent = convertFile(unpackedData);
        console.log("Time to convert file: " + (performance.now() - t1) + " ms");
        ...
      
        const newFile: IOpenFile = {
          id: uuid(),
          fileContent,
          ...
        };

        state.openFiles[newFile.id] = newFile;

        console.log("Time to open file: " + (performance.now() - t0) + " ms");
    },
```

The result is not what I expected:

- Time for dispatch: 400-450 ms
- Time to open file: 100-120 ms
- Time to convert file: 85-90 ms

The results are stable over multiple runs.

Is this normal? If so, what could the reason for the extra 300ms in the dispatch over the reducer be?

Comment: What do you want to save?
saving fileContent can be the issue maybe.
Can you save the file content in fs and just use a uuid to point it when needed?

Comment: What sentance makes you think I want to save something? The file we're opening contins graph data, so I want it in Redux state in order to show the data to the user.

Comment: Just in case, the culprit could be devtools if its active, otherwise I have no Idea what could cause it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, based on the fact that you're mutating your state, that you're using `createReducer` or `createSlice`, the extra time is probably because [Redux uses Immer to iterate over the state object to see what you mutated](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#redux-toolkit-and-immer). If the files you're loading are large, your state object is probably pretty complicated, so Immer may be taking a while to iterate over everything.

> Immer works by tracking attempts to mutate an existing drafted state value. ... In any given case reducer, Immer expects that you will either mutate the existing state, or construct a new state value yourself and return it, but not both in the same function

You have to read between the lines a bit in the documentation, but essentially: If Immer sees that you returned a new state object, Immer will not try to iterate over the state object to try to detect mutations.

So to optimize this reducer, you have to manage making a deep copy of the state yourself:

```
setNewOpenFile: (
    state,
    action: PayloadAction<{
        filePath: string;
        unpackedData: ParsedFile;
      }>
    ) => {
        const t0 = performance.now();
        const { unpackedData, filePath } = action.payload;

        const t1 = performance.now();
        const fileContent = convertFile(unpackedData);
        console.log("Time to convert file: " + (performance.now() - t1) + " ms");
        ...
      
        const newFile: IOpenFile = {
          id: uuid(),
          fileContent,
          ...
        };

        const copyOfState = {...state, openFiles: {...state.openFiles}};

        copyOfState.openFiles[newFile.id] = newFile;

        console.log("Time to open file: " + (performance.now() - t0) + " ms");
        return copyOfState;
    },
```

Then Immer should see that you returned `copyOfState`, which is a different object ref than `state`, and won't try to detect where you did mutations, so it will skip the slow iteration over the state object.

You probably want to be creating these state copies yourself and returning them in all your reducers, if your state object is so large that it takes a few hundred ms to iterate over everything. Otherwise Immer will cause similar performance problems in all your reducers, even ones that aren't setting large files like setNewOpenFile.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for your elaborate answer.
You are correct, I'm using `createSlice`. The entire state is fairly big, but not this particular slice. Copying the slice state and returning a new object didn't increase the performance, but I guess the same applies to the root reducer where the slices are combined?

Comment: Hmm. If copying the slice didn't improve the performance then I'm stumped where the extra few hundred ms is coming from. I still think it must be from some Redux code that runs as part of processing your reducer, but aside from Immer, I'm not familiar enough with Redux internals to suggest any other culprits